# 504 Not connected Error in IB API TWS- even though API connection shows 'accepted'

Tags: python, tws, ib-api

I have made numerous attempts to write IB API code which all are producing the `-1 504 Not Connected error`. Even with code directly and exactly from the IBKR academy training videos (which i have pasted below). I have checked and rechecked over and over the Global Settings `Enable ActiveX & Socket` is ticked, Socket Port # is 7497, Client ID's match btw API code & TWS, Allow Connections from localhost is selected, input '127.0.0.1'and localhost:5000 into trusted IP's

The Data Connections table in TWS shows API connections listening on 7497 Peer-to-Peer Port 127.0.0.1.60104 Client ID 1 as Accepted; which indicates the API is connected...however when I select Run nothing happens - I just get a print of the file link in the VS Code Python terminal, and when I execute Run Python Debugger - I receive the following:

```
PS C:\TWS API\source\pythonclient\ibapi>  & 'c:\Users\JV\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe' 'c:\Users\JV\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.2.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '60548' '--' 'c:\TWS API\source\pythonclient\tests\TestApp.py'

ERROR -1 504 Not connected

PS C:\TWS API\source\pythonclient\ibapi>
```

I have searched and searched for answers on this and other forums. Can somebody please help this newbie who seems to be pinned down and struggling to get off the first base with IB API? Thank you.

```py
from ibapi.client import *
from ibapi.wrapper import *
import time

class TestApp(EClient, EWrapper):

    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)

    def contractDetails(self, reqId, contractDetails):
        print(f"contract details: {contractDetails}")

    def contractDetailsEnd(self, reqId):
        print("End of contractDetails")
        self.disconnect()

def main():
    app = TestApp()

    app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7497, 1)

    mycontract = Contract()
    mycontract.symbol = "AAPL"
    mycontract.secType = "STK"
    mycontract.exchange = "SMART"
    mycontract.currency = "USD"
    mycontract.primaryExchange = "ISLAND"

    time.sleep(3)

    app.reqContractDetails(1, mycontract)

    app.run

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is `app.run` is a method call so needs to be `app.run()` .

Your code has other common ib-api problems and you should search here by clicking my name then the relevant issue.  Most examples are like yours and are incorrect.

Comment: Hi Brian .... THANKYOU SO MUCH for answering so quickly ...i am extremely grateful. Your answer fixed the problem. I am also extremely embarrassed it is such a simple resolution and error on my behalf. I put it down to extreme tiredness. I have seen a lot of your answers throughout my searches - i will certainly click on your name and review. Thankyou for sharing your knowledge - it is a great contribution to this world